# How to verify an apk's signature with openssl

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, pyopenssl

I write a python application to analyze apk files. To check the signature of the apk I run the following command:

```
jarsigner -verify <path to apk>
```

via subprocess.
For performance reasons, I want to use openssl instead of jarsigner.

Is there a way to do this like:

```
openssl verify <path to apk>
```

?

Comment: No. `jarsigner` does multiple verification steps, as explained [here](http://www.pa.msu.edu/reference/jdk-1.2.2-docs/tooldocs/win32/jarsigner.html#Verifying). This is not supported as a single command to the `openssl` tool.

Comment: which commands do I need to do the checks with openssl?

Answer (score 4):

To fully verify an APK's signature and integrity, for each signer:

1. Check that the signature block file META-INF/<signer>.[RSA|EC|DSA] is a valid PKCS #7 CMS signature of the corresponding META-INF/<signer>.SF file. This can be achieved using:
   $ openssl cms -verify -content META-INF/CERT.SF -in META-INF/CERT.RSA -inform DER -noverify
2. Check that the digest of META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is the same as specified in the META-INF/<signer>.SF <digest alg>-Digest-Manifest attribute (base64-encoded). Python/shell trickery and/or OpenSSL's "openssl dgst -binary -sha1 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | base64" could help here.
3. For each file listed in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, check that the digest of that file matches the digest listed in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. Again, Python/shell/OpenSSL trickery...
4. Check that there are no files in the APK which aren't listed in MANIFEST.MF (except for signing-related files from META-INF).

If you only need to extract each signer's cert, and don't care whether the APK has been tampered with after signing, you can limit yourself to step 1.